# How can I redirect all pages of a subdomain to the add-on pages?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, url-rewriting, add-on

basically , google is listing all subdomain pages of my add-on domain.

google lists
http:// www. mymainwebsite.com (which is good)

but also

http:// www. subdomain . mymainwebsite.com  (which is not good)

So.......... in the htaccess I added this:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.mymainwebsite.com$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.subdomain.mymainwebsite.com$

RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\://www.mymainwebsite.com/" [R=301,L]

This works for the main subdomain, BUT I can "still access" all of the subdomain pages,  e.g.  I can still access: 
http:// www. subdomain.mymainwebsite.com/about

Google has listed 'hundreds' of these above subdomain "pages"

So my question is...  is there any 'code' that i can add in my htaccess, which redirects "ALL" the subdomain "pages" which have unfortunately been listed in google?

I want http://www.subdomain.mymainwebsite.com/about (faq/history/contact/links, and hundreds more pages)

to goto

http://www.mymainwebsite.com/about (faq/history/contact/links, and hundreds more pages)

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the rewrite engine to add the rest of the URL to the rewrite.

It should look something like this:

RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ "http\://www.mymainwebsite.com/$1" [R=301,L]

That will redirect all paths on your subdomains to your main domain.

The $1 is a backreference to the (.*), which matches all characters after the slash. Using the $1 includes those characters in the redirect.